# How do I create several related data types in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

I have a `User` type that represents a user saved in the database. However, when displaying users, I only want to return a subset of these fields so I made a different type without the `hash`. When creating a user, a `password` will be provided instead of a `hash`, so I made another type for that.

This is clearly the worst, because there is tons of duplication between my types. Is there a better way to create several related types that all share some fields, but add some fields and remove others?

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #}

data User = User {
  id :: String,
  email :: String,
  hash :: String,
  institutionId :: String
} deriving (Show, Generic)

data UserPrintable = UserPrintable {
  email :: String,
  id :: String,
  institutionId :: String
} deriving (Generic)

data UserCreatable = UserCreatable {
  email :: String,
  hash :: String,
  institutionId :: String
} deriving (Generic)

data UserFromRequest = UserFromRequest {
  email :: String,
  institutionId :: String,
  password :: String
} deriving (Generic)

-- UGHHHHHHHHHHH
```

Comment: Why do you need UserPrintable at all?  Just create a `showPrintable ::User->String` function.

Comment: I suspect you are trying to solve the wrong problem. What are you trying to achieve? If you are just interested in a subset of fields under different circumstances then just pass the whole type. Maybe you need to replace UserFromRequest with a function that computes the hash from the password.  BTW, have you considered where salts will go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I think you can replace your various `User` types with functions. So instead of `UserFromRequest`, have:

```
userFromRequest :: Email -> InstitutionId -> String -> User
```

Note how you can also make separate types for `Email` and `InstitutionId`, which will help you avoid a bunch of annoying mistakes. This serves the same purpose as taking a record with labelled fields as an argument, while also adding a bit of extra static safety. You can just implement these as newtypes:

```
newtype Email = Email String deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Similarly, we can replace `UserPrintable` with `showUser`.

`UserCreatable` might be a bit awkard however, depending on how you need to use it. If all you ever do with it is take it as an argument and create a database row, then you can refactor it into a function the same way. But if you actually need the type for a bunch of things, this isn't a good solution.

In this second case, you have a couple of decent options. One would be to just make `id` a `Maybe` and check it each time. A better one would be to create a generic type `WithId a` which just adds an `id` field to anything:

```
data WithId a = { id :: DatabaseId, content :: a }
```

Then have a `User` type with *no* `id` and have your database functions work with a `WithId User`.